# How to Make a web page download PDF, DOC, POWER POINT and images

Tags: php

I have been trying to make a download page that would download different file formats (PDF, DOC, POWER POINT and images). This works with pdf, but the first problem is that sometimes it makes my whole system reboot or it redirects to other pages whose contents are not human readable. Secondly, the other file formats (MIME) that are not application/pdf would not just download, sometimes the pdf downloads but when I try to open it an error message would be displayed, saying its a bad file format. Below are the headers I use to make the download page.

```
header('Content-Type: application/{$_GET['mime']}');
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename='{$_GET['name']}'\n");
header("Content-Length:{$_GET['size']}\n");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

The following are the various MIME I tried to allow:

```
$permitted = array('text/html', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg','image/gif',
 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 
 'application/pdf', 'text/plain', 
 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
 'application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.presentationml.presentation');
```

Here's the code (almost) all together:

```
$flag = false;
$filepath = $_GET['path'] . $_GET['name']
foreach($permitted as $value) {
    if($_GET['mime'] == $value) {
        $flag=true;
        break;
    }
    if($flag == true) {
        header('Content-Type: application/{$_GET['mime']}');
        header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename='{$_GET['name']}'\n");
        header("Content-Length:{$_GET['size']}\n");
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        readfile($filepath)
    }
```

I would appreciate all responses as I am using this for my project in school, Thanks....

Comment: Get the details of the file from the file, not from user input.

Comment: This might not specifically solve it, but if you're trying to use single/double quotes or variables inside of strings, you should either use the correct quotes or escape the quotes, ex: `header('Content-Type: application/{$_GET['mime']}');` should instead be: `header("Content-Type: application/{$_GET['mime']}");`. Also, are you getting anything in your error logs that might be of use?

Comment: @Quentin, The information is gotten from a database table, I also tried using filesize(), for the size of the file, all worked the same way, with the same trouble

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge — If it comes from a database table, what is it doing in `$_GET`?

Comment: @emma.fn2, there is nothing from the error log

Comment: @Quentin, a page contains an anchor tag that has href attribute directed to the page where the headers are sent. it is from the anchor tag page that the information are collected from the db and placed as GET with the href like this <a href='dashboard.php?path=/../&name=...&size=...'

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge — You're trusting that it won't get modified by the user or an attacker (who might give the link to someone else).

Comment: @Quentin, Well I just want it to work first

Comment: @Quentin, but that is the only way I know how to do it..... If there is another way I would be glad to have it

Comment: You get the details out of the database when the file is requested (instead of when the link is generated).